# Dictionary Composition and updating values via list entries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have two lists train_label and train_data and I want to iterate through each row i, which is done by for i in range(train_data.shape[0]), I want to update each value in my dictionary such that at the jth key will have the corresponding ith entry of the list. So I constructed this list comprehension, however it only updates each value of the dictionary to the first value in the list, is there a way to do this using list-comprehension so that each jth key will have the ith value in each key, value pair?

```
assoc_label = {}
 _ = [assoc_label.update({entry : assoc_label.get(entry, train_label[i])}) for entry in range(train_data.shape[0] - 49997) for i in range(train_label.shape[0] - 49997)]
```

EDIT: Added additions per @Scott Hunter suggestion

So, train_label would be some list say [6.0, 4.0, 6.0], train_data would be some numpy array of floats such as [0.0123123, i, j] however the content isn't important I just want to associate each position in the numpy array [0, 1, 2], which are my keys in the dict {0: 1: 2:} with the values in the train_label list which are [6.0, 4.0, 6.0] which results in a dictionary such that I have {0: 6.0, 1: 4.0, 2:6.0} otherwise {entry: train_label[i]} however the dict will only update all values to the 0th value of train_label[i] such that {0:6.0, 1:6.0, 2:6.0}. I hope I didn't make explaining this too convoluted, I just wanted to be exact as possible.

Comment: Please provide sample data and an example of what this is supposed to accomplish; even better would be demonstration of what it does that is incorrect.

Comment: Does `dict(zip(range(3), [6, 4, 6]))` do what you have in mind? Your explanation could be a lot clearer. Try making it a programming question instead of a question about your specific data.

Comment: Yes! @ChrisP the following code would be,   `assoc_label = dict(zip(range(train_data.shape[0]), [train_label[i] for i in range(train_data.shape[0])])) print assoc_label`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer credit to @ChrisP would be to use zip, rather than two for loops:

```
 assoc_label = dict(zip(range(train_data.shape[0]), [train_label[i] for i in range(train_data.shape[0])]))
print assoc_label
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that? I'm not sure I understood the question.

```
import numpy as np

train_label = [6.0,4.0,6.0]
train_data = np.array([0.01,0.04,0.07])
assoc_label = {i : train_label[i] for i in range(len(train_label))}
print(assoc_label)
```